# jquery form plugin isn't work with change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to upload a file with jquery.form plugin but the action isn't work with change function based on input type file.

This is the code:

HTML :

```
<form method='POST' id='upload_image' action='ajax-upload_unpublished_image' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file' id='photo_post' name='posting_photo'>
</form>
<div id='#prev'></div>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#photo_post').change(function(){
            alert('ganti');
            $('#upload_image').ajaxForm({
                  beforeSend: function(){
                    $('.uu').html('sending');
                },
                  success: function(html){      
                $('#prev').html(html);   
            },
            error: function(data){
            console.log(data);

            }
            });
        });
});
```

I want the file to upload at every input change, like facebook upload photo, why is the ajaxForm function not working, while if I use another button to do the ajaxForm function with a click function, the file uploads.

like :

```
<button class='upload'>Upload</button>

$('.upload').click(function(){
   //do ajaxForm function and it work
});
```

Comment: what is your website?

Comment: no,it is still in localhost

Comment: I mean what kind of website is that?

Comment: @Kermani sharing about traffic jam with photo

Answer (score 0):

I dug around and this seems to work for other people.

```
$('#photo_post').on('change', function(){  });
```

Comment: Your code works fine when I test it in fiddler (http://jsfiddle.net/yQa62/). What browser are you using? Are you getting any javascript errors on the page?

Comment: sure the on change function is work, but ajaxForm isn't